# Move array to the right, and make missing space 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to move an array to the right by a set value, and replacing the now missing spaces with 0. I just can not figure out how to do it.

Array before moving:

`let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

Array after moving 2 to the right:

`array = [0,0,1,2,3,4,5]`

Ive looked at other stack overflow posts but those just wrap around the data making a move to the right look like this:

`array = [6,7,1,2,3,4,5]`

Whilst I want to just remove the 6 and 7.

Comment: Please show what research you've done and what attempts you've made based on that research.

Comment: No, Im not looking to add new data just shift everything to the right and replace the gap with 0.

Comment: It does provide part of the answer to your question if you'd just apply yourself a bit

Comment: @Samo2120 You *are* looking to add new data. The new data is `0`. Just do it in a loop `n` times.

Comment: No because the array isn't fixed, in the example it just makes the array longer, Im looking to keep it the same length

Comment: @Barmar A loop? Seriously? For somebody who's rep on here is so high that is an egregiously horrible suggestion.

Comment: And you can keep it the same length, IF YOU'D ONLY JUST APPLY YOURSELF

Comment: @Dexygen Unless you're inserting hundreds or thousands, the O(n^2) complexity is not a big deal.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon Didn't notice that.

Comment: Just `unshift` with 0's and the `pop` off the last numbers, and do that in a loop, O(n^1)

Comment: @Samathingamajig Each unshift is O(n), so this is O(n*m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `unshift` with 0's and the `pop` off the last numbers.

```js
function shiftArray(arr, numberOf0s) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOf0s; i++) {
    arr.unshift(0);
    arr.pop();
  }
}
```

```js
function shiftArray(arr, numberOf0s) {
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOf0s; i++) {
    arr.unshift(0);
    arr.pop();
  }
  return arr;
}

let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

console.log(array);

shiftArray(array, 2);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

As with most languages manipulating an array type data structure anywhere other than the back via methods like `insert`, `unshift` is not ideal. This is because of the way elements of an array are stored in memory i.e., contiguously. For this reason, each `insert` or `unshift` operation requires moving all the elements after it every time to maintain this "contiguousness". Basically, you should avoid using these methods unless you absolutely have to when working with arrays.

Luckily in this case you can just iterate over the array in reverse and copy the element to its correct position and fill in the remaining slots with zeros for an O(n) solution where `n` is the length of the array:

```js
const moveToRight = (array, n) => {
    if (array === undefined || array.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (n < 0) {
        throw 'Error n cannot be negative!';
    }
    let i = array.length - 1;
    while (i >= 0 + n) {
        array[i] = array[i - n];
        i--;
    }
    while (i >= 0) {
        array[i] = 0;
        i--;
    }
    return;
}

array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
try {
    moveToRight(array, 2);
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
console.log(array);
```